# Invalid use of group function in mysql

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I've a table like this:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | salary |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | Ajay |  20000 |
|  2 | Aja  |   2000 |
|  3 | Aj   |    200 |
|  4 | A    |   3000 |
|  5 | q    |  30000 |
+----+------+--------+
```

I want to write a query that can print highest salary, medium salary and lowest salary. So I wrote this query:

```
select salary 
  from parent
 where max(sal) 
    && salary < ( SELECT MAX( salary )
                   FROM parent ) 
    && min(salary);
```

And mysql returned an error:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

what is the correct query?

Comment: what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't offer an aggregate function to grab a median value, sorry to say. Hopefully you can go with the average (the arithmetic mean) value.

Stuff like `MAX()`, `MIN()`, and `AVG()` (called *aggregate functions* in the jargon of SQL) can't appear in `WHERE` clauses.  They can show up in `SELECT` and `HAVING` clauses. That's why you got an error.

You'll be wanting

```
SELECT MAX(salary) max_salary, 
       AVG(salary) avg_salary,
       MIN(salary) min_salary
  FROM parent
```

If you control your own MySQL server and you have a few MySQL dba chops, you can install a user-defined function to compute the median value. (If you're using a hosting service with a multitenant MySQL server, forget about this.) Read this.

http://mysql-udf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: As an aside, median UDFs and sprocs are available.

Answer (score 0):

`select 'min' as k, min(salary) as v from parent
union
select 'avg' as k, avg(salary) as v from parent
union
select 'max' as k, max(salary) as v from parent`